# ul li 2nd line text not properly align after using li:before

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a common problem but it seemed that I can't solved it. I tried to look for answer but still didn't solved my problem.

I have an ul li. The li was set to list-style:none, I use li:before to put custom bullets.

The problem I am facing is that the second line of text don't align to the above text when the container is small.

[image]

I want to achieve the result the same as the image above on the right.
How can I perfectly align the 2nd line of text?

Thanks for help.

EDIT:

```
This is my sample code from <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/bo1nvxop/">jsfiddle</a>
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example using the `+` as the bullet point. Depending on what character you will be using for the bullet point, you may need to adjust the negative text-indent.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 1em;
  text-indent: -0.825em;
}

ul li:before {
  content: "+ ";
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</li>
  <li>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `position: absolute;` for your `:before` pseudo class. This will then allow you to position the bullets wherever you want without affecting the text in the element.